# C++ sorting array => vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a simple struct

```
struct test 
{
    std::vector<Data> data;

    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    }
}
```

Data is a struct as well and has only simple fields and implements a < operator like following:

**EDIT: changes according to feedbacks are included**

```
struct Data 
{
    // ADAPTION 1 - comparator works with reference now
    bool operator<(const Data &data) const
    // bool operator<(const Data data)
    {
        // 1) sortieren nach Typ
        if (type < data.type)
            return true;
        else if (type > data.type)
            return false;

        // 2) nach name sortieren
        if(strlen(strName) > 0)
        {
            if (strncmp(strName, data.strName, 50) < 0) 
                return true;
            else if (strncmp(strName, data.strName, 50) > 0)  
                return false;
        }
        // ADAPTION 2 - added:
        else if (data.strName[0]) // at least 1 character...
             return true;

        // 3) nach Spezialtyp sortieren
        if(strlen(typeSpecial)>0)
        {
            if (strncmp(typeSpecial, data.typeSpecial, 50) < 0) 
                return true;
            else if (strncmp(typeSpecial, data.typeSpecial, 50) > 0) 
                return false;
        }
        // ADAPTION 3 - added:
        else if (data.strName[0]) // at least 1 character...
             return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

That's it. How can I get the `vector iterators incompatible` error that way? I'm not copying any vector, I'm directly calling the sort function with the vector...

In Visual Studio 2005, I've never had a problem, in Visual Studio 2012 this problem appeared and I don't know why and how to avoid it

Comment: I guess your `operator<` is part of a class? But what is `STAT_DATA`?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the Data struct... And I edited my post... I replaced STAT_DATA with a simplier name Data...

Comment: Could you quote the exact error message and indicate the related line(s) ?

Comment: First try making the comparison operator `const`: `bool operator<(const Data& data) const { .... }`, just to remove a potential source of error.

Comment: we need complete & minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Looks like the iterators are incompatible because sort() will copy the vector as your operator< is not accepting Data by reference.

Comment: it copies the element(s), not the vector.

Comment: Complete code example illustrating the problem would be ideal.  Failing that, the data members / constructors / assignment operators and destructor for `Data`.

Comment: that's not complete code. we need something which can be tested immediately. where's you `main`? make sure it reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There're a few issues with your code:

```
bool operator<(const Data data)
```

...should be...

```
bool operator<(const Data& data) const
```

Then:

```
    if(strlen(strName) > 0)
    {
        if (strncmp(strName, data.strName, 50) < 0) 
            return true;
        else if (strncmp(strName, data.strName, 50) > 0)  
            return false;
    }
```

...needs...

```
    else if (data.strName[0]) // at least 1 character...
        return true;
```

This is required to ensure strict weak ordering, which is a requirement of `std::sort`'s and means that when `a < b`, `!(b < a)`.

Similarly:

```
    if(strlen(typeSpecial)>0)
    {
        if (strncmp(typeSpecial, data.typeSpecial, 50) < 0) 
            return true;
        else if (strncmp(typeSpecial, data.typeSpecial, 50) > 0) 
            return false;
    }
```

...needs...

```
    else if (data.typeSpecial[0])
        return true;
```

Your string comparisons would be much cleaner if you used `std::string`s.  If you do stick with ASCIIZ data, it would be better to use e.g. `sizeof typeSpecial` instead of `50` etc..  You can improve performance and code concision by doing less comparisons and trusting `strncmp` to handle empty strings appropriately (which it will):

```
if (type < data.Type) return true;
if (type > data.Type) return false;

int d = strncmp(strName, data.strName, sizeof strName);
if (d == 0)
    d = strncmp(typeSpecial, data.typeSpecial, sizeof typeSpecial);
return d < 0;
```

Comment: but this doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: I'll try the const... The rest is not true though, see the last line of my function, it returns false... That's what I want, it's a tree like sorting function... If a higher level is empty or the same, I want to check the sorting level below... and so on...

Comment: "The rest is not true though, see the last line of my function, it returns false" - so?  `std::sort` requires the comparison to have "strict weak ordering" (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)).  That means if `a < b`, then `!(b < a)`.  Without the changes I suggested, that condition does not hold for your code, which can lead to corruption of data, failure to sort, and quite possibly the error you document.

Comment: ok, now I see what you mean... I changed my code (I made the operator const and working by reference and I added your code suggestions)... But still, I get the same error...